# Am i correctly trying to update a record in a database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, materialize

I'm trying to update a record in a database. The records and some fields are shown on a page in a table. Upon pressing the edit button next to a record in the webpage, it takes the user to a new page with where the information for that record is displayed on a new page with the data for that record inside textboxes.

Im not sure what the problem is, at first I thought it was the variable names, but I don't think so anymore.

```
<form action="../models/updateReview.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="hidden" name="reviewId" value="<?php echo $indStmt['revid']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" name="author" class="validate" value="<?php echo $indStmt['author']; ?>">
      <label class="author">Author</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" name="location" class="validate" value="<?php echo $indStmt['location']; ?>">
      <label class="location">Location</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" name="rating" class="validate" value="<?php echo $indStmt['rating']; ?>">
      <label class="rating">Rating(1-5)</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" name="review" class="validate" value="<?php echo $indStmt['review']; ?>">
      <label class="review">Review</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row center">
    <button class="btn-large black" type="submit">Edit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```php
<?php

$reviewId = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'reviewId', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$reviewName = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'author', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$reviewLocation = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'location', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$reviewRating = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rating', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$reviewMessage = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'review', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

if (empty($reviewName) || empty($reviewLocation) || empty($reviewRating) || empty($reviewMessage)){
    echo "Invalid Data Entry. Please check all field and try again";
}else {
    require('dbConnect.php');

    $statement = $connection->prepare('UPDATE tblreviews SET author = :author, location = :location, rating = :rating, review = :review WHERE revid = :reviewId');

    $statement->bindValue(':author', $reviewName);
    $statement->bindValue(':location', $reviewLocation);
    $statement->bindParam(':rating', $reviewRating);
    $statement->bindParam(':review', $reviewMessage);

    $statement->execute();

    header('Location: ../views/reviews.php');

}

?>
```

The first block of code is the form page that appears when the edit button is pressed. The second one is the process of me trying to update the actual record. It gets past the execute and takes users back to the main page as if it works, but the record isn't actually updated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like you're missing a bind for reviewId. You should also add a check to see if any rows were modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comment - you did not bind the `reviewId` to the statement. Here is another approach that makes it a little more automated as the parameters for the sql statement are created automatically if no errors are detected. Using an approach like this means the sql doesn't get executed unless the various tests return true

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* the sql to be executed */
        $sql='update `tblreviews` set `author`=:author, `location`=:location, `rating`=:rating, `review`=:review where `revid`=:reviewid';



        /* fields and their filters */
        $args=array(
            'reviewId'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'author'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'location'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'rating'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'review'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        /* placeholder arrays */
        $errors=[];
        $params=[];

        /* Check that all fields are populated */
        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( !isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'The field %s is not set', $field );
        }

        /* check that there are not spurious additional fields in the POST array - or ones forgotten about */
        foreach( $_POST as $field ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field %s', $field );
        }

        /* no errors, proceed */
        if( empty( $errors ) ){

            /* filter the POST array & generate variables */
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );


            require 'dbConnect.php';

            /* create the params array for use in the prepared statement - using "variable variables" */
            foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field )$params[ sprintf( ':%s', $field ) ]=${$field};



            /* prepare & execute the sql statement */
            $stmt=$connection->prepare( $sql );
            $status=$stmt->execute( $params );

            /* redirect */
            exit( header( sprintf('Location: ../views/reviews.php?status=%s', $status ? 'ok' : 'error' ) ) );

        }else{
            /* There were errors ... */
            echo "Invalid data entry. Please check all fields and try again";
            printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($errors,true));
        }
    }
?>
```